# Keycloak - Switch to another User Federation provider for a User

Tags: active-directory, keycloak

I have defined two User Federation providers on my Keycloak (`providerA` and `providerB`). Now, I have a user (`usernameOne`) which is currently linked to `providerA` and I want to change `usernameOne`'s Federation link to `providerB`.

Is this possible in Keycloak? I was thinking we can delete the user and then re-sync using the other provider but this does not seem ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @stephen, unfortunately, no. We ultimately ended up directly calling the LDAP server from our Java code using Ldaptive.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try to play with these buttons under User Federation > providerA, probably Unlink users is what you want.

I would created TEST-realm with both providers and tried in there first :)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for answering! Is it possible to do this on a per-user basis? Unlink users does this for all users linked to `providerA`, however, our requirement is for this to be done to a single user at a time.

Comment: What I would do in your place, maybe play around "Custom User LDAP Filter" for your providerA and limit it to one user, like (sAMAccountName=**John.Smith**), that means your user federation providerA is responsible for syncing one user "John.Smith", now press "Unlink users". Go to providerB, filter by "John.Smith" again, Synchronize all users in providerB. So we emulated single user at a time :). At least custom filter gives you flexibility on failing thst task for a single user or group of users, not for everyone under provider.

Comment: You might better ask keycloak official forum for such specific requirements https://keycloak.discourse.group/.     Please comment later what you done and have you found a solution, for future references.